# SharePoint 2010: How to add custom element to Create menu?

Tags: custom, custom-actions, silverlight, web-part-page

I want to add custom element to SharePoint 2010 Create menu. (Site Actions -> View all site content -> Create). I want to to add this element to Page directory like a "Web Part Page" element. How can I do it? Thanks a lot in advance.